# Fire base data to ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I show the data of firebase in place page as show in code . but i only show the title and area in place.html .now i want the other information like description and also image in next page i try it but the error shows the description is not defined in tour.ts.

firebasedata

```
{
  "Places" : {
    "Hunza" : {
      "area" : "Gilgit-Baltistan",
      "description " : "Hunza Valley is a mountainous valley located in Gilgit, which is an area under the government of Pakistan. The main town of Hunza, Karimabad (formerly known as Baltit) is the capital as well as most popular tourist destination of Hunza.",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travelagencyapp-36c03.appspot.com/o/places%2Fhunza.jpg?alt=media&token=61c34018-ef64-43e9-a285-3ad1b9ebd3be",
      "season" : "May - June",
      "title" : "Hunza"
    }
  },


}
```

dataprovider

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';



@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public afDB : AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello DataProvider Provider');
  }

   getPlaces()
  {
    let ref = this.afDB.list('Places').snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes =>{
      return changes.map(c=> ({key:c.payload.key,...c.payload.val()}));
    });

    return ref;

  }



}
```

place.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { TourPage } from '../tour/tour';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';



/**
 * Generated class for the PlacesPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-places',
  templateUrl: 'places.html',
})
export class PlacesPage {



places: Observable<any[]>;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public authProvider: AuthProvider, public dataProvider : DataProvider
  ) {
 this.places = this.dataProvider.getPlaces();

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PlacesPage');
  }



 logout() {
    this.authProvider.logout();
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }

  tour(place) {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(TourPage,{data:place});
  }





}
```

places.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Places</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content class="card-background-page" >



 <ion-card  *ngFor="let place of places | async" (click)="tour()">
      <img height="170" src="{{place.image}}">
      <div class="card-title">{{place.title}}</div>
      <div class="card-subtitle">{{place.area}}</div>
    </ion-card>



  </ion-content>
```

tour.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DataProvider } from '../../providers/data/data';


/**
 * Generated class for the TourPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tour',
  templateUrl: 'tour.html',
})
export class TourPage {

data: any;
description: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {


  this.data = this.navParams.get('data');
  this.description = this.data.description;

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TourPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Your description has a space inside the key value.

Comment: <ion-card *ngFor="let place of places | async" (click)="tour()">

Your not passing any data into the function tour() in places.html, it needs to have tour(place) to post across the data, but you may have to do this inside the loop and not on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Your (click)="tour()" is not passing any data into the tour function.
tour() requires at least one parameter to be parsed into it which is place.

```
tour(place) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(TourPage,{data:place});
}
```

So when you navigate to TourPage the {data:place} will be empty.
Try changing:-

```
<ion-card  *ngFor="let place of places | async" (click)="tour()">
```

to

```
<ion-card  *ngFor="let place of places | async" (click)="tour(place)">
```

It that does not work, you will need to parse the (click) event inside the loop.